# row_number with partition value changing

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this piece of sql code that finds the row_number based on some values in a table __working that joins into a lookup table __Eval

```
;WITH r 
 AS (
    select 

    w.uid,
    t.TypeId,
    --weight
    ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY w.uid ORDER BY  DIFFERENCE(t.val1, w.val1) +  DIFFERENCE(t.val2, w.val2) + DIFFERENCE(t.val3, w.val3) + DIFFERENCE(t.val4, w.val4)  DESC) as Score
    ,w.account

    from __Working w
        join __eval t on w.val1 like t.val1 and IsNull(w.val4, '') like t.val4 and IsNull(w.val2, '') like t.val2 and IsNull(w.val3, '') like t.val3

)

select * from r     where   r.account = 1 and score = 1
```

this returns a typeId = 1

however if I write it like this

```
   ;WITH r 
     AS (
        select 

        w.uid,
        t.TypeId,
        --weight
        ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY w.uid ORDER BY  DIFFERENCE(t.val1, w.val1) +  DIFFERENCE(t.val2, w.val2) + DIFFERENCE(t.val3, w.val3) + DIFFERENCE(t.val4, w.val4)  DESC) as Score
        ,w.account

        from __Working w
            join __eval t on w.val1 like t.val1 and IsNull(w.val4, '') like t.val4 and IsNull(w.val2, '') like t.val2 and IsNull(w.val3, '') like t.val3
            where   r.account = 1
    )

    select * from r     where   r.account = 1 and score = 1
```

it returns TypeId = 2.  I would expect that if i had multiple UIDs across different accounts in __working, but I don't.  What am i missing here?

Comment: Why filter on r.account in the CTE and again int he select? Filtering inside the CTE is going to change your ROW_NUMBER()

Comment: Gordon answered correctly.  The one thing to note though is that DIFFERENCE(t.val1,NULL) would be NULL.  And NULL + 1 Is NULL, so if even 1 of your columns in the DIFFERENCE functions can be null your entire order by becomes a NULL.  I would guess you might want to do some NULL handling but not sure of your use case

Comment: yeah, val1 is a non-nullable field, so that didn't need the null checking, but thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, this is a weirdness of unstable sorts.  Your `row_number()` expression is:

```
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY w.uid
                    ORDER BY  DIFFERENCE(t.val1, w.val1) +
                              DIFFERENCE(t.val2, w.val2) +
                              DIFFERENCE(t.val3, w.val3) +
                              DIFFERENCE(t.val4, w.val4)  DESC
                   ) as Score
```

The problem is that multiple rows have the same value for the `ORDER BY` key.  Different invocations arbitrary choose which of these multiple rows is first, second, and so on.

The canonical solution is to include some sort of unique key so the sort is stable:

```
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY w.uid
                    ORDER BY  (DIFFERENCE(t.val1, w.val1) +
                               DIFFERENCE(t.val2, w.val2) +
                               DIFFERENCE(t.val3, w.val3) +
                               DIFFERENCE(t.val4, w.val4)
                              ) DESC,
                              ??  -- perhaps typeId
                   ) as Score
```

However, I might suggest a more arduous solution.  Accept the fact that ties might exist, and use `rank()` and `dense_rank()` to identify them.  Then, figure out *explicitly* what to do in the case of a tie -- perhaps all are equally interesting to you or perhaps you have some other method of breaking ties.

Comment: Oh thank you so much.  So the lookup table is constructed to actually not have ties, so when you said that that pointed me to the answer.  The real problem is the use of the difference function, which doesn't actually do what I thought it did.  It rates the two strings on a scale of 0-4 based on the soundex, whereas i thought it would give me the difference in charecters.  I'll have to reconsider what function to use there, or write my own